# Пунктуация в сложном предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

> Но, к счастью её, она почувствовала, что глаза её разбегались: она ничего не видела ясно, пульс её забил сто раз в минуту, и кровь стала стучать у её сердца.

Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку запятых.

Comment: @Aer Объясните, пожалуйста, почему Вы убрали метку "л-толстой"? Это ведь не какое-то абстрактное предложение, а цитата из романа "Война и мир" (так и оформлено — как цитата). А в моем ответе есть ссылка. Подскажите, что я сделала неправильно?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова а зачем нужна эта метка? В чем смысл указывать авторство высказывания в метках?

Comment: Я ориентировалась на то, что есть используемая метка "пушкин". Этот вопрос был бы уже шестым с "толстовским направлением" — а вдруг кому-то надо будет посмотреть вопросы-ответы именно по Толстому?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Поддерживаю использование этой метки. Всегда полезно знать, кому принадлежит предлагаемое в вопросе предложение.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова метку Пушкин и все подобные я бы удалил: слишком много будет бесполезных меток. Тютчев, Фет, Некрасов, Черубина де Габриак, Чёрный... подтянутся. Вы можете инициировать обсуждение на Мете, конечно же. Свое мнение я высказал.

Answer (score 2):

(1) *Но, к счастью её, она почувствовала,* (2) *что глаза её разбегались:* (3) *она ничего не видела ясно,* (4) *пульс её забил сто раз в минуту,* (5) *и кровь стала стучать у её сердца.*

Это сложное предложение с различными видами связи:
**1, 2** — подчинительная с союзом "что" (перед ним ставится запятая);
**3, 4** — бессоюзная (между двумя простыми предложениями ставится запятая);
**4 и 5** — сочинительная (между двумя простыми предложениями, связанными союзом "и", ставится запятая);
**(1, 2): (3, 4, и 5)** — бессоюзная (ставится двоеточие).
Упрощенное предложение (только с основами):
Она почувствовала, что глаза разбегались: она не видела, пульс забил, и кровь стала стучать.

*К счастью её* — это вводное словосочетание, которое выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.
[К СЧАСТЬЮ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_382), *вводное слово*
Вводное слово «к счастью», а также вводные сочетания «к счастью (для кого-либо, чьему-либо)», выражающие эмоциональную оценку сообщаемого, обособляются.

Стоит отметить, что в некоторых изданиях "к счастью её" не выделено запятыми ([**см.**](http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=18555&public_page=120)). Я считаю, что это все-таки вводная конструкция, поэтому запятые нужны.

[Запятая перед союзом «и»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/v-kakih-sluchayah-pered-soyuzom-i-stavitsya-zapyataya.html)
[Бессоюзное сложное предложение](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/755-32_znacheniya_slozhnyh_bessoyuznyh_predlozhenii_i_znaki_prepinaniya_v_nih.html)

Comment: Эх-эх, пока отвечала, вопрос почти закрыли. Жаль! Я старалась...

Comment: Римма, спасибо за развернутый, очень точный ответ. Я отозвал свой голос за закрытие.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Александр. Надеюсь, что все действительно правильно — давно "разборками" не занималась.